# Passing a JS callback function to C# RT Component error: "Unable to cast object of the type 'mydb.SQLite3JSNoCallback' to 'mydb.SQLite3JSNoCallback'"

Tags: c#, javascript, callback, windows-runtime

I have a Javascript Windows 8 App. I am writing a WinRT Component DLL using C# for interfacing with a database.

For all functions such as OpenDB, ExecuteUpdate, ExecuteQuery (returning one row, returning one column value), I have done a IASyncOperation and am pretty successful.

But for processing each row in a big resultset, one by one, I need to pass in a callback function from javascript to the C# WinRT Component DLL. so the code is like,

```
My.WinRT.Component.Object.processEachRowASyc(query, arguments, function(row) {
    /* Row specific processing */
}).then(function(result) {
    /* Process after Entire Row processing is Complete */
});
```

I have written the RT Component such as this,

```
namespace mydb
{
    public void delegate MyJSCallback(string msg);
    public class Database {

        public static IAsyncOperation<Database> OpenDB(string dbFile)
        {
           /* Open DB */
        }

        public IAsyncOperation<Database> ProcessEachRowASync(string sql,[ReadOnlyArray()] object[] arg, MyJSCallback myJSCallback)
        {
            return Task<Database>.Run(() =>
            {
            /* Query Processing */
            IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string toRet = "{\"Name\":\"Raju\", \"Age\":\"21\"}";

                //Javascript callback function called.
                myJSCallback(toRet);
            }
            return this;

            }).AsAsyncOperation();
        }
    }

}
```

Now, I am getting a typecasting error when I execute this from Visual Studio, I am sure I am erring somewhere in declaring the delegate or somewhere else,

Can somebody please enlighten me on where I am doing wrong and how this could be corrected.

[image: Error Message]
URL for downloading a sample project for this is, http://sdrv.ms/18ff3Hl

To simplify this further, I have written another function in the RTComponent showing just the callback error, the code is as follows in the RT Component

```
public delegate void SQLite3JSNoCallback();
public IAsyncOperation<int> GetLastInsertRowId(SQLite3JSNoCallback someCallback)
{
    return Task<int>.Run(() =>
    {
        someCallback();
        return 0;
    }).AsAsyncOperation();
}
```

Now the error occurs in while performing someCallback(), the error is as same as the above screenshot with the change of the delegate alone. "Unable to cast object of the type 'mydb.SQLite3JSNoCallback' to 'mydb.SQLite3JSNoCallback'."

Comment: I am pretty sure you want to use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx instead of `Serialize(myMap);` because your inability to communicate well I won't be returning to this question.  I am tired of having to read a new block of code every 2 hours.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, believe as GetLastInsertRowId(SQLite3JSNoCallback someCallback) function also fails other Objects and function calls are irrelevant to the issue faced.

Comment: Update the question with the exact error because its not the one caused by the other line of code.

Comment: now removed all code which are misleading, just hard coded what I am expecting from the other code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I removed the IASyncOperation from the function, the js callback worked without issue.

There seems to be a problem because I am having a blocking callback function sent as the parameter, I believe. Can any one clarify how it can work with IASyncOperation present in my function.

Should I send in an ASyncCallback function to the C# RT Component to be able to get a callback.

Still the answer remains for the above problem to make the RT Component's function a blocking function if you need a javascript callback to successfully work,

Regards,

Jay

Answer (score 5):

This happens because of asynchronicity, as you have noticed. I have found that by invoking the callback on the UI thread, it will now work as expected.

### WinRT component:

```
public delegate void DoStuffCallback(int num);

public sealed class Test
{
   public void ShowStuffOnOutput(int x, int y, DoStuffCallback callback)
   {
       Debug.WriteLine("pre-callback");
       Debug.WriteLine(x);

       Task.Run(() =>
       {
           callback(15);
       });

       Debug.WriteLine("post-callback");
       Debug.WriteLine(y);
   }
}
```

### Javascript universal app

```
 var obj = new CallbackComponent.Test();

 obj.showStuffOnOutput(1, 2, function(num) {
     console.log("callback in JS!");
     console.log(num);
 });
```

### Solution:

Switch to

```
CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.
 Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High, () =>
{
    callback(15);
});
```